# My WPF application doesn't open after I put an image through XAML (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have some practice with Windows Forms, but now I decided to experiment with WPF in Visual Studio; Through XAML I have put an image in the Grid, called Street2.jpg, and the image can be seen in the studio.
  But if I try to start the application it just doesn't open (altough it generates a proccess in my task manager), and if I debug it, a message is shown:

[image]

Here's my XAML code (I haven't inserted anything in the C# code yet):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WhenItAllEndedWPF.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Background="{x:Null}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\Street2.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>

</Grid>
```

What could I do to fix this problem? Thanks for the help!

[EDIT]

This was showed in the output tab:

The thread 0x1f0c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'WhenItAllEndedWPF.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WhenItAllEndedWPF.vshost.exe): Loaded 'c:\users\vini\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\When It All Ended WPF\WhenItAllEndedWPF\bin\Debug\WhenItAllEndedWPF.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WhenItAllEndedWPF.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WhenItAllEndedWPF.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: See the Inner Exception...

Comment: The inner exception will be more useful, its likely its something along the lines of "Cannot locate resource 'images/Street2.jpg"

Comment: I am really sorry; for those of you asking for the inner exception, I am searching for what exactly it is and how to get it; Sorry, I am a beginner self-taught programmer and still don't know many things.

Comment: @ViniciusKriegerGranemann Set a breakpoint at the first line in the constructor of MainWindow (at `InitializeComponent()`). When the debugger stops there, step over the line (e.g. by pressing `F10`). Now you get an exception popup in the debugger. Click "View Detail...", open the exception properties and take a look at the `InnerException` property.

Comment: And have you really made sure the the image file is part of the Visual Studio project, in a folder "Images", and the Build Action is `Resource`?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I made sure, it's even in the Solution Explorer Window, Build Action set to Resource, and I can see the image in the MainWindow; but I am having problems with what you told me about breakpoints, because when I press F10 it justs pops-up the same message I have put in the question, and there's no "View Detail" there

Comment: I am sorry, I feel really dumb now, this looks like a really basic thing I should know how to do

Comment: Or write a try/catch block around the InitializeComponent call a set a breakpoint at the catch. As soon as the debugger stops there, inspect the caught exception.

Comment: Sure you're running the Debug version of your program?

Comment: Check the build action of your image, and your slash is wrong it should be Images/Street2.jpg. Also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be because the file that you have specified has not been found ("Images/Street2.jpg")

Please see the inner exception.. I expect something such as this...

> "Cannot locate resource 'images/Street2.jpg"

Please ensure that the file exists in the location you are expecting it: The build action should be Resource (the default).

Also.. Visual Studio will give intellisense for the image path so just check that you have not done something silly such as use the wrong extension (jpg / jpeg) which is something I do from time to time.

Comment: From the question: "the image can be seen in the studio". Certainly no wrong extension then.

Comment: @Clemens How about submitting an answer as opposed to picking fault in everyone else's efforts?

Comment: Sure, but I prefer to wait until OP has told us what the InnerException *actually* is, instead of just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making sure that the image is set to content in your solution explorer? This can be done by right clicking selecting properties and then changing "Build Action" to "Content".

Comment: Actually Build Action should be `Resource`, and the image file should be contained in a folder "Images" in the Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify Image source like this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/WhenItAllEndedWPF;component/Images/Street2.jpg" />
```

It should be valid if your projet name is WhenItAllEndedWPF and if You have Street2.jpg inside Images folder in projects root.

Also check, is your jpg file is included in project (visible in solution explorer when non-included files are hidden).

Also ensure, that your output folder or files in it are not locked by some other application.